# (Closed) JSON to CSV conversion for LARGE DATASET

Tags: json, csv

I have a .txt file with over a million JSON entities in it with varying keys generated from a python program. This is just an example.

```
{
    "category": "Athlete", 
    "website": "example.com", 
    "talking_about_count": 560, 
    "description": "xxx", 
    "id": "123"
}
{
    "category": "Community", 
    "talking_about_count": 0, 
    "name": "The Second Civil War",
    "likes": 26, 
    "id": "234", 
    "is_published": true
}
```

Even though each JSON has different attributes, they do have common attributes. 
The resulting .csv file would have the columns category, website, talking_about_count,description,id,name,likes,is_published like this

```
"category","website","talking_about_count","name","likes","description","id","is_published"
"Athlete","example.com","560","","","xxx","123",""
"Community","","0","The Second Civil War","26","","234","True"
```

https://json-csv.com/ does this beautifully but is not able to handle datasets with more than 1000 entities.

I would like to create a CSV from this .txt file containing a million JSON entities and I was wondering if there is a better way to go about this.

Comment: you could try their desktop converter, it says it can do any size file https://json-csv.com/download

Comment: @maxymoo Thankyou! I will try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

If the file `filter.jq` contains

```
  (reduce (.[]|keys_unsorted[]) as $k ({};.[$k]="")) as $o   # object with all keys
| ($o  | keys_unsorted), (.[] | $o * . | [.[]])              # generate header and data
| @csv                                                       # convert to csv
```

and `data.json` contains the sample data then the command

```
jq -M -s -r -f filter.jq data.json
```

will produce the output

```
"category","website","talking_about_count","description","id","name","likes","is_published"
"Athlete","example.com",560,"xxx","123","","",""
"Community","",0,"","234","The Second Civil War",26,true
```